# Angular reactive form with custom form-level validator AND updateOn 'blur' option doesn't works

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have problems combining :

- angular reactive form
- custom validator at form-level (cross-field validator)
- usage of the 'updateOn' option set to 'blur'

I made a simple stackblitz to show the problem :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-url9uc?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

**CASE 1 : KO**

'updateOn' option set to 'blur'.

We can see that specific field validators (required / email) are correctly fired, only when we loose focus on the input text field.

BUT the cross-field global validator (check that fields are the same) is not fired!

**CASE 2 : OK**

'updateOn' option is not defined.

We can see that specific field validators (required / email) are correctly fired, in real time each time a value change in the input text field.

AND the cross-field global validator (check that fields are the same) is correctly fired!

**I guess I have a problem in my custom validator or the way I use it, but I don't manage to figure it out why...**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll take a look at your stackblitz, you'll see that in your `buildForm()` and `buildForm2()` you're using deprecated overload of the `formbuilder.group()` with signature:

```
(controlsConfig: { [key: string]: any; }, options: { [key: string]: any; })
```

You should use type-safe version:

```
(controlsConfig: {
    [key: string]: any;
}, options?: AbstractControlOptions)
```

What this means in practice? The configuration part of your form should have `validators` instead of `validator` (note the plural version):

```
validators: CustomValidator.equalValueValidator("email", "confirmEmail"),
```

Then everything will work as expected and `updateOn` will be actually used for the validators.

Comment: wow, indeed this seems to work well! Sorry I missed this deprecated method. Thanks a lot for the help